# Position change animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have div element and I want to animate its CSS relative position from left:-260px;  to left: -130px; over 0.5s when I put my mouse over it and I want it to stay there as long as my mouse is over that div. Than I want to animate it back to where it was when I move my mouse out of that div.

I read tons of tutorials on css keyframes animations and I'm very confused.
I want something really simple. Just ease animation that lasts 0.5s.
How can I do it using css or CSS+JavaScript (no jQuery) ?

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code so we can see you have at least attempted it.

Comment: i tried a lot of stuff. Most of i tried to figure out by myself. Like using javascript to change element id when mouse is over, and then in css i used that changed id to set different parameters.
I also tried using only ccs keyframes and i got it to move and stay there but i couldnt get it to be animated back when i moved my mouse out. It would just jump to its original position instead.
Id rather not post my code here because it so messed up now and it serves no purpose. I'm going to have hard time untangling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
 .myclass {
     transition: 0.5s;
 }

 .myclass:hover {
      /* add relevant vendor prefixes */
      transform: translateX(130px);
      transition: 0.5s;
 }
```

EDIT:
Proof of concept: http://codepen.io/Theodeus/pen/oXWEYx

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way to do what i need, but if I wanted to change some other properties i would stick to 3rd solution (http://jsfiddle.net/jcng5un4/1/) by @G.L.P

Comment: @OskarEriksson according to your links it is supported with prefixes if you want wide browser support...

Comment: @KirillSlatin yes - thus the comment in the CSS to add the prefixes as needed. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @OskarEriksson I am used the fact that transitions are multi-line definitions and expected to see full (ready-to-use) solution like the one posted by G.L.P

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcng5un4/1/)**

css:

```
ul li{ 
    padding-left:260px;      
    -moz-transition: padding-left .3s ease;
     -o-transition: padding-left  .3s ease;
     -webkit-transition: padding-left  .3s ease;
     transition: padding-left  .3s ease;
    display:block;
    }

ul li:hover{
    padding-left: 130px;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## div1 {

```
    transition-property: transform;                
    animation: example 5s infinite linear;
```

}

```
  @keyframes example                 
            {
        100%{-web-kit-transform:translate X(0px);}            
          0%{-web-kit-transform:translate X(150px);}
   }
```